# How to access variables and methods from QMainWindow Class in a QWidget Class - Python PyQt5

Tags: python, class, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm building a media player with PyQt5 in python and I want to access variables from my QMainWindow class. Currently I have two classes - one is the main window (QMainWindow) and the other is a QWidget Window so called my export manager.

Some basic code of my structure

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        
        # create gui
        # some basic functions


    # A function for opening a video with selection of file in explorer

    def OpenVideo1(self, filename1=None):

        file_filter = 'Video file (*.mp4 *.avi *wmv);'

        filename1 = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            parent = self,
            caption='Select a video file',
            directory = os.getcwd(),
            filter = file_filter,
            initialFilter='Video file (*.mp4 *.avi *wmv)'
        )[0]

        ....

    # On button click the export manager window opens

    def OpenExportManager(self, checked):
        self.Exp = ExportManager()
        self.Exp.show()

class ExportManager(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

    # Some gui functions etc...

    def exportvideo
       # Here I want to excecute some commands for export one video
       # Therefore I need variables from the MainWindow - in this case filename1 and others

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    Main = MainWindow()
    Main.show()
```

My question is now: How can I access the MainWindow variable filename1 from my ExportManager class? And how can I access methods the same way?

I tried already with signal/slots from pyqt5 or some class instances but I'm stuck...

Thanks very much for your help!

PyQt5 signals and slots but I got stuck.

Comment: You could for example simply pass along any attributes that your `ExportManager` needs, e.g. do `ExportManager(filename1)` (and add the argument in the `__init__` of your `ExportManager` class. But it also depends on what you would like to do.

Comment: Yes thanks - thats the way to go!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a point about Object-Oriented Programming more than about GUI.

You could keep track of the `filename1` variable by making it a member of the `MainWindow` class.

In `MainWindow.init()` you could add :

```py
    self.chosen_filename: str = None
```

Then you assign it at the end of the `MainWindow.OpenVideo()` method

```py
    self.chosen_filename = filename1
```

When you instantiate the `ExportManager` object, you can pass the filename as a constructor argument.

```py
def __init__(self, parent=None, filename=None)
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I implemented it and it works - for sure its more object-oriented programming then. In case I want to handover (many) more variables is it still the best way or is there another solution then? And what if I want to access methods of the MainWindow Class?

Comment: Of course you can extend the concept.
In case you have many variables that are related you could make an object of that variables and associate some behaviour by adding methods. For example a `Video` class with a filename variable, a bytestream, some video-processing methods.
Technically nothing prevents from passing the `MainWindow` object in the `ExportManager` constructor in order to access both variables and methods.
It might not be the best way. The point is to find the best way to structure your code. A good starting point is try to keep separated GUI stuff and functional stuff.